# How to filter data in a pageBlockTable through an inputCheckbox

Tags: apex, visualforce, criteria-filter, apexinputcheckbox

I have a pageBlockTable that returns data from any query, in that result one of the columns returned is a picklist.

I added an InputCheckbox just above the pageBlockTable and I would like that when the user clicked on the inputCheckbox the search would be re-made considering the value of the inputCheckbox. How can I make this work without adding a search button?

Page:

```
<div style="float:right;">
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fieldFilter}" onclick="{!LoadGrid}"> 
        Check to filter
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:form>
</div>
<br />
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="result">
        <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!result.name}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Description" value="{!result.description}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Check">
            <center><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!result.flag}" disabled="true" /></center>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Created date" value="{!result.createdDate}" />
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

[image: Image of grid and filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [apex:actionSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) component will help. It makes asynchronous requests to the server to get the specified part of the page re-rendered with the current data.

Use it like this:

```
<apex:form>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fieldFilter}"> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="pageBlock"/>
        </apex:inputCheckbox>
    </div>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="result">
            ...
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Note that at the server-side, the `results` content will need to be updated to match the `fieldFilter` property.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you